# How to display WordPress post content in multiple block elements without page refresh

Tags: javascript, wordpress, post

I'm gonna post a fiddle because it's easier to explain.

http://jsfiddle.net/EhNKM/84/

```
$("#focus a").mouseenter(
    function(){
        this.style.color = '#cc0000';
        $('<p>content from post that the hovered-over link points to.</p>').replaceAll('#child p');
    }
);
```

How can I access post information that is referenced by a link to that post content? I'd like to use that information to load that post content into another div, but I'm just not sure where to begin with this (what WordPress PHP can I use? JS?). Anything, even screaming at me for being dumb, would be helpful!

To clarify what's going on in the fiddle,

1. Once a user hovers over a link (to another post), the child div loads that linked-to post content.
2. Don't worry about the .click() event. I'm sure solving the above would provide insight into this.

Thanks!

EDIT:
I also believe I should use

```
this.getAttribute('href')
```

to get the linked-to post, but I'm not sure what wp function I should (or could!) use to get the content of that post once I have the reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using `jQuery ajax`, well, follow my instructions step by step.

**1.** Create a folder in your theme folder `js`, suppose your theme folder is twentytwelve, so it should be

```
http://yourDomain.com/wp-content/themes/twentytwelve/js
```

**2.** Create a file into your `js folder` and name it `myScript.js`

**3.** In your `functions.php` file add

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','my_theme_scripts_function');
function my_theme_scripts_function() {
    wp_enqueue_script('myScriptHandler', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myScript.js');
    wp_localize_script( 'myScriptHandler', 'myAjax', array( 'ajaxUrl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
```

**4.** Also add following code in your `functions.php`

```
function do_myAjaxFunction()
{
    $post_id = url_to_postid($_POST['post_url']);
    $post = get_post( $post_id, OBJECT);
    $response = apply_filters( 'the_content', $post->post_content );
    echo $response;
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myAjaxHandler', 'do_myAjaxFunction' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myAjaxHandler', 'do_myAjaxFunction' );
```

**5.** Now in the `myScript.js` file, add following code

```
$('.your_post-entry a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var currentUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    $.ajax({
        type : 'post',
        url : myAjax.ajaxUrl,  
        data: {
            action: 'myAjaxHandler',  
            post_url: currentUrl  
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('#ajax_post').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Put the above code inside `jQuery(function($){...});` function (the ready event of jQuery). It' done! Now you can fetch your post content using `ajax`.

---

### Explanation :

When you'll click any link inside the element (assume a div) with class name `your_post-entry`, the click event will fire (You know that) and it'll send a post request to `http://yourDomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` because `myAjax.ajaxUrl` contains that `url` and it's (myAjax object) available to our script through `wp_localize_script` that we have in our `functions.php`. The `ajax` request will also send some variables to the `$_POST` array and those are `action` and `post_url`, the `post_url` contains the `permalink` of the post and `admin-ajax.php` will run our `do_myAjaxFunction` which will fetch the content of the post and send it back to the browser because we've added actions using `add_action( 'wp_ajax_myAjaxHandler', 'do_myAjaxFunction' )`, which tells the `WordPree` that whenever you get an ajax request for `myAjaxHandler` action, please run the `do_myAjaxFunction` function. The first `add_action` is `wp_ajax_nopriv_myAjaxHandler`, which is required to make the ajax request work even when user is not login in the wordpress backend, without `wp_ajax_nopriv_myAjaxHandler` the ajax request won't work if the user is not logged in. Notice the line `$('#ajax_post').html(data);` in the `success` callback, it'll insert the returned data into the `element/div` with an `id` of `ajax_post`, so make sure to use appropriate `id` and `class` name in the click event.

If you don't want to use `ajax` for every post then you can add/generate a `class` for those `post links` that you want to use ajax, for example, `ajaxPost` and in the click event you can use

```
$('.your_post-entry a.ajaxPost').click(function(e){ ... });
```

Now you know how to do it so I think you can do it using `mouseenter` instead of `click` if you need to do this way (you gave an example of mouseenter).

**Some usefull links :** [wp_ajax_](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29) and [how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress](http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/18/how-to-use-ajax-in-wordpress/)

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks so much! I ended up defining ajaxurl with `<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>` inside some js, but all works well! And thanks for the resources too, I've been scouring smashing mag the entire day

Comment: quick question. I also notice that the .mouseenter() (or .mouseclick()) function runs only once. This appears to be because of it being nested inside the .ready() function, but I'm unaware of any other way to run the .mouseenter() function. Is this a simple fix? Or should I post a new question? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I should clarify: including `<?php wp_head() ?>` within the head allows me to continuously use the functions `$('#focus a').mouseenter(function(e){...});` and `$('#focus a').click(function(e){...});`, but after new content is loaded into the <div> with id=#focus, the methods no longer work for the targeted `#focus a` values.

Comment: @user2407984, You should use `$(document).on('click', '#focus a', function(){ ... })` and same for the `mouseenter` event as well.

Comment: @user2407984, You cal also replace the `(document).on({...})` with `('parent container id/class of focus').on({...})`.