# Add a WordPress action during Ajax call

Tags: wordpress

I included a file (`some-file.php`) in my Ajax callback function. In that file I added some actions:

```
// some-file.php
add_action('load-post.php', 'function1');
add_action('load-post-new.php', 'function2');
```

But the functions (`function1` and `function2`) never executed, however I'm positively sure that `some-file.php` is included.

`add_action` works perfectly if I called it inside my plugin file directly. I have problem with it when I'm calling it inside my Ajax callback.

Why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Read the documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_action

Comment: Could you please tell me which part of this documentation is related to my question?

Comment: The use of add_action()

Comment: I updated to be more specific.

Comment: Are you initializing Wordpress in the Ajax callback? What errors are you seeing in the Ajax? (Look at the request's response body in the developer tools)

Comment: No errors. I want to enable some functionality due to user call (e.g. Do sth after a post is published if this feature is enabled). Response is OK and the file will be included too. But the actions does not triggered.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you have the Wordpress environment loaded in your Ajax callback?

Comment: I strongly suspect this ain't gonna work. What `function1` and `function2` are supposed to do? And most important, **where** is this Ajax action being called?

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16704717/how-to-display-wordpress-post-content-in-multiple-block-elements-without-page-re/16707074#16707074), you'll get an idea.